# mvn spring-boot:run vs java -jar xxx.jar performance difference

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jsf-2, embedded-tomcat-8

In my project i use spring-boot with jsf. When i start my web application from IDE(eclipse) or using 'mvn spring-boot:run' command there is no problem response time is very good. But when i package my app with ' mvn clean install ' and than run 'java -jar myapp.war' sometimes it takes too long time to process simple jobs. For example opening a dialog page with some data from backing bean, normally takes 200 msec but sometimes it takes 7 secs. What can it be the cause of this problem ?

Not: I face this problem only running it with packaged fat .war file.

Comment: If you're just running them blindly, I'd expect them to have different configurations regarding memory and such. You might be experiencing a stop-the-world GC when you're getting excess latency.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Kayaman. Yes I am running with no configuration. But when i monitor the activity of gc and cpu with VisualVM, I don't see any GC activity but cpu increases up to 30-40% when i come accross this problem. Actually there is nothing requires that much of cpu.

Comment: If you have VisualVM in use, use it to see what's happening instead of asking us. If you don't know how to use VisualVM properly, start learning. It can tell you a lot more than just "30-40% cpu usage".